# Why does variable of Data Type SByte using expression evaluate to 0?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I'm trying to set some variables of type SBYTE to null at runtime using an expression directly on the variable. The variable is scoped to the control flow.

Why does the variable evaluate to 0 instead of null? How can I set it to null?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because SSIS variables cannot be `NULL`. Oddly, I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141085.aspx) that explicitly says that they can't be `NULL`, it just says

> The value of a user-defined variable can be a literal or an expression

But an (old) [Microsoft blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2007/06/15/optional-date-parameter.aspx) says "If SSIS variables supported NULL values..."  and the [Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Integration Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111810112X) book [says](http://books.google.com/books?id=7_g0SocQ3CcC&pg=SA6-PA7&lpg=SA6-PA7&dq=ssis%20variable%20default%20value&source=bl&ots=LMDF3X95nJ&sig=v7EKclJsQ9qas28W9LAsR7twS24&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WI55UcrmAoGm8ATW5oDACg&ved=0CIYBEOgBMAk#v=onepage&q=ssis%20variable%20default%20value&f=false):

> In SSIS, variables can't be set to `NULL`. Instead, each variable data
>   type maintains a default value in the absence of a value.

And indeed, if you evaluate just `NULL(DT_UI1)` you get zero; evaluating `NULL(DT_BOOL)` gives `False`; evaluating `NULL(DT_DATE)` gives `12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM`.

And using an expression to set a variable to `NULL` doesn't work either: if you create an `Int32` variable, set `EvaluateAsExpression` to `True` and enter the value `NULL(DT_UI4)` then you get the error "Property value is not valid", with the detailed message "NULL(DT_UI4) is not a valid value for Int32".

Comment: Great explanation. I guess I can remove the variables that need to be set to null and operate on them in the SQL Statement right?

Comment: Yes, I would keep the logic in SQL if possible (without knowing what your package logic is). Personally I try to avoid using expressions unless absolutely necessary because building and debugging them is so awkward and they're also so easily overlooked ('forgotten' is probably more accurate). But they definitely have their uses so don't hesitate to use them where they're helpful.